# Table will not display

Tags: php

I am having no success linking the upper part of the code containing the prepared statements to the table display. After eradicating several syntax errors, all I am getting now is a single row of numbers starting at 0 and running through to 2713 instead of the database results. The code below is exactly as I am using it except that for this purpose I have removed my personal details from the '$con'

```
 <?php

 $con= new PDO('mysql:host=;', "", 
 "");
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  if (isset($_POST['submit-keyword'])) {
  $keyword = '%'.$keyword. '%';
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bath_Wells_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE :keyword ORDER BY DATE");
  $stmt->bindParam(':keyword',$keyword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
 //use fetchAll to get full array of results, or an empty array
  $result=$stmt->fetchAll();
 if(count($result)>0) {
 print "<table>";
//return only the first row (we only need field names)
$row = $result;
print " <tr>";
foreach ($row as $field => $value){
print " <th>$field</th>";
} // end foreach
print " </tr>";
//second query gets the data
$data = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bath_Wells_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE :keyword ORDER BY DATE");
$data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $row){
print " <tr>";
foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
print " <td>$value</td>";
} // end field loop
print " </tr>";
} // end record loop
print "</table>";
}
}
```

?>
\\

Comment: `$keyword = '%'.$keyword. '%';` -> did you mean `$keyword = '%' . $_POST['submit-keyword'] .  '%';`? (Also, please reformat your code, it's very hard to read. Hopefully it's not like that on your actual files.)

Comment: Have you tried `echo` instead of `print`?

Comment: Thank you Johannes. The table code with a straight forward 'db connect' and 'SELECT * from ...' works perfectly well as written on another page, so I don't think 'print' rather than 'echo' is the problem.

Comment: Thank you Jeto. $_POST ['submit-keyword'] refers only to the submit button and not the user user input which I have named 'keyword'. It is the user input that I want the database to search for. Other have also commented on reformatting my code but personally I find it easier to follow if the first character of each line is vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1):

your second query not get bind param properly

[See Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

```
$data = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bath_Wells_NBR WHERE Founder LIKE :keyword ORDER BY DATE");
$data->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rows = $data->execute();
```